# Deploy Files to Windows Host Machines from Jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment, msdeploy

I've Jenkins installed on a Windows server and I wishes to copy the published VisualStudio files to multiple Windows Hosts [LoadBalanced environment].

What is the most recommended way to copy files from Jenkins [hosted on windows] to multiple windows hosts, running on a LB farm. Is there any direct plugin for this?

If there any direct ways of copying the build files to destination servers, apart from multiple jenkins build steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) you can split a task into multiple tasks which can then be executed [in parallel](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/). You could do something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            parallel {
                stage('build-1') {
                    agent {
                        label "windows"
                    }
                    steps {
                        bat "build-1.bat"
                    }
                }
                stage('build-2') {
                    agent {
                        label "windows"
                    }
                    steps {
                        bat "build-2.bat"
                    }
                }
                stage('build-3') {
                    agent {
                        label "windows"
                    }
                    steps {
                        bat "build-3.bat"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The files would be copied from your SCM (Subversion, Git, etc) and the build scripts would be launched to perform whatever build actions you need to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the points. Do you have any suggestion in copying the files to multiple remote windows server from jenkins? Or, can this be done using msdeploy?

Comment: Typically this is done by checking out from a source control system (Subversion or Git or simliar) using the `checkout scm` directive but nothing stops you from pulling or pushing artifacts through other means (like msdeploy). The only trick is if you decide to roll your own solution you're responsible for making sure builds don't collide with each other. For instance if two builds are started at the same time you could accidentally wipe out a workspace that's being used.